# Google Maps API 3 MarkerClusterer with json

Tags: json, maps

I have google maps reading a json file to show the lat/long.  The json file was from the example provided but I added my own json data at the top of the file.

The problem is, when I start deleting some of the example json data, the map stops showing the markers.  My json data set is about the first 100 records.

Right now, I'm limiting the count to show only the first 102 records, but would like to eliminate all the example json data?

Sample at http://www.dwellcation.com/maptest2.html

Comment: Solved! - deleted an extra comma- Duh!